# Replace a string in attribute value in a xml using xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I am a novice in XSLT. I have been trying to transform a XML for a longtime but unable to do.
The input XML is like this:

```
<Load v:MajorVersion="05" v:MinorVersion="01" xmlns="version 2" xmlns:v="version 2">
  <annotation/>
  <Header></Header>
  <Body></Body>
</Load>
```

The output should replace the value of attributes `xmlns` and `xmlns:v` from `version 2` to `version 1` if its value is `version 2`, otherwise it should be left as is.
The problem is that the attributes are prone to change, and the input xml could be like `xmlns:n`, or `xmlns:m`, or these attributes may not even exist.

Finally we should search for all attributes of node `Load` and search for string `version 2` in all the attributes (like xmlns, xmlns:v, xmlns:n, etc)
and replace by `version 1`.

Please help me. Trust me I have spent hours finding an answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

your attributes are namespace declaration. Therefore have a look for "How To Change the URL of a Namespace".

You may try something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:v2="version 2">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
          </xsl:copy>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="v2:*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" xmlns="version 1">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>  
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@v2:*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}" xmlns="version 1">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet
```

Comment: thanks, I have seen the above solution. The problem is, the namespace qualifier is dynamic, it may come as v2, or, pidx, even something else. Also there can be multiple namespace declaration having the value as "version 2". the purpose is to replace all namespace declaration, from "version 2" to "version 1"

Comment: You are talking about namespace prefixes for the same namespace uri. They do not matter. You only need a unique prefix in your xslt which does not need to be the same as in the xml. Try the above templates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think in terms of the XPath data model, not in terms of the source XML. If you understand the data model for your XML fragment, you will appreciate that you don't want to change the value of the `xmlns` attribute, you want to change the namespace part of the element and attribute names; that is, you want to create new elements/attributes whose names have the same local name but different namespace URIs from the old elements/attributes. So you want instructions like

```
<xsl:element name="name()" namespace="...."/>
<xsl:attribute name="v:majorVersion" namespace="...."/>
```